Signed ssh certificates not working (Hashicorp Vault)
I’ve recently been trying out Hashicorp Vault and finding it very useful.
I’m trying to setup signed ssh certificates to login to my remote hosts/servers, as per this guide:
https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/secrets/ssh/signed-ssh-certificates
I sent the public .pem file of Vault to the target host that I want to login to and pointed to it in
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
using
TrustedUserCAKeys /etc/ssh/trusted-user-ca-keys.pem
I generated a public private key pair on my client. I got the public key signed by Vault on my Vault server using that guide and sent it back to the client.
I am able to ssh into the target host fine with either password or private key ssh. What I am unable to get working is ssh with the signed public key and also to force it to use only that method.
Here are the commands I have tried adding to the host (Debian) /etc/ssh/sshd_config settings file:
usePAM no
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
PubKeyAuthentication no
Here is the ssh command I’m using:
ssh -v -o “IdentityOnly yes” -o CertificateFile=“/path/to/signedcert.pub” -i “/path/to/privatekey” user@IP
The -v outputs indicate that it tries the various options but ultimately the signed certificate doesn’t work and it gets back to password authentication (which is also unclear to me since I thought my commands in sshd_config would be enough to disable that…). I am running
sudo systemctl restart sshd, when making these changes on the target host.
Any advice or suggestions would be very much appreciated on this as I’m feeling quite stuck but probably missing something obvious…
Thanks for your help!

Hard to say what your exact issue might be; one very common issue with identity files and certs in this area are file-/directory permissions that are too lax. Typically you don't want at least the last dir in the chain to either be group/world (0700) accessible, and for the private file the perms on the file need to be 0600 as well. Similarly the dir that the last dirrectory level of the path lives in shouldn't be group or world writable ...

@tink :  Thanks for the suggestion! This is my first time delving beyond standard ssh key based auth ie. using signed certificates. Can you advise on what permissions I should set to each folder and file? I had not paid too much attention to this so it could well fix things, thanks! Are there any logs or debugging steps I can follow to narrow down the problem?

In light of the fact that you gave fake paths I came up w/ generic instructions; try to follow those. As for debugging. You could start the sshd on the remote end interactively w/ debug turned on (that should tell you why which method is failing) ...

Thanks! I just wasn’t clear on exactly what permissions to set but I will experiment with this and see how it goes. The only fake paths are ones that would otherwise expose personal information about me since my understanding is that one should avoid sharing such things on the internet. They are both under the user directory for the user trying to do the ssh.
I will look into how to start sshd interactively!
Thanks again for the things to try!

As I said: 0700 on the dirs, 0600 on the files ...

Many thanks, that seems to be working now!

As per the solution in the discussion on the question.
Make sure the files and directories in which the public & private cert/ID live have sane permissions.
0600 for files, 0700 for directories, including the parent directories of the last step directories not being group-writeable.
